# MySQL updates column to always NULL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables which basically one is a master table and the other one is a table for developers. From time to time I would copy review the record from the developer table and move it to the master table:

--SHOW CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT --

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `source_type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_crawled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `html_content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `dev` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `dev_document_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `promote` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`url`(500),`dev`,`dev_document_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=628871 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

--SHOW CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_DEVELOPER--
CREATE TABLE `document_developer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `jurisdiction` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_crawled` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `mime_type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `html_content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `date_posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `url_promote_UNIQUE` (`url`,`promote`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=637067 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (promote)
(PARTITION part0 VALUES IN (-5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part1 VALUES IN (-4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part2 VALUES IN (-3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part3 VALUES IN (-2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part4 VALUES IN (-1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part5 VALUES IN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part6 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION part7 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

### The column of dev_document_id will be the id of record in document_developer once the copy is done.

However, when i try to run update as below:

```
UPDATE document as d INNER JOIN document_developer AS dd ON d.dev_document_id = dd.id 
SET
d.content=dd.content
WHERE dd.modified='1' AND dd.promote='2';
```

it will always give me erroneous content value such as NULL NULL NULL ... Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe `dd.content` is `NULL`

Comment: document_developer AS da. BUt in condition used dd.id.Change it to da

Comment: typo on my end.. its should all be dd.. not da.. but it still erroneous. And no, content is not NULL unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
UPDATE document as d INNER JOIN document_developer AS da ON   
d.dev_document_id = da.id 
SET
d.content=da.content
WHERE da.modified='1' AND da.promote='2';
```